# $\nabla_{E_j\circ \phi^{-1} } f= \nabla_{E_j} (f\circ \phi)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

$\nabla_{E_j\circ \phi^{-1} } f= \nabla{E_j} (f\circ \phi)$?

Suppose that $S=g^{-1}(0)$ for some smooth map $g:\mathbb R^{n+1}\to \mathbb R$ such that $\nabla g(x)\ne 0$ for every $x\in S$.

For a smooth map $X:U(\subset \mathbb R^{n})\to S(\subset \mathbb R^{n+1}), p\in U$ and $v\in \mathbb R_p^n$, define $\nabla _v X=dX_p(v)$, where $dX_p$ represents the derivative of $X$ at $p$.

Let $\phi: U\to S$ be a local diffeomorphism and $f:S\to \mathbb R$ be smooth. Let $E_k(q):= d\phi_q(e_k), q\in U$.

Then it is to be shown that $\nabla_{E_j\circ \phi^{-1} } f= \nabla_{E_j} (f\circ \phi)$.

LHS $=df(E_j\circ \phi^{-1})=df(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_j}\circ \phi^{-1})=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial x_j}\circ \phi^{-1}$.

RHS $=d(f\circ \phi)(E_j)=df(d\phi(E_j))=df\left(d\phi\left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_j}\right)\right)$ by Chain rule in the second equality.

I don't understand how to show LHS=RHS from here. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, given a diffeomorphism $\phi\colon U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\to S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, for any $j=1,\ldots,n+1$, you denote by $E_j$ the map $$E_j\colon U\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n+1},\ q\longmapsto(T_q\phi)(e_j),$$
where $T_q\phi\colon\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\overset{\sim}{\to}\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is the tangent map (or derivative) of $\phi$ at $q\in U$.

If this is correct, then (given a smooth function $f\colon S\to\mathbb{R}$) I do not think that the identity you want to show holds in its current formulation.

Indeed LHS and RHS denote two maps having different domains of definition. Precisely, $$\nabla_{E_j\circ\phi^{-1}}f\colon S\to\mathbb{R},\ x\in S\to(\mathrm{d}f)(T_{\phi^{-1}(x)}\phi)(e_j),$$
$$\nabla_{E_j}(f\circ\phi)\colon U\to\mathbb{R},\ q\in U\to(\mathrm{d}(f\circ\phi))((T_q\phi)(e_j)).$$

The only relation that I see is the obvious one: $(\nabla_{\phi_\ast e_j}f)\circ\phi=\nabla_{e_j}(f\circ\phi)$, where both sides are smooth functions from $U$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

**Edit (after the OP added some context)** I was not familiar with the notation used in that reference, and so my understanding was wrong. I will rewrite the computation on page 183 of the provided reference using more standard notation.

Consider a $n$-dim mfld $S$, and a coordinate system $\phi\colon U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\to S$.
Pick a local frame $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ of vector fields on $U$ and the local frame $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ of vector fields on $\phi(U)$ such that $Y_i$ is the *pushforward of $X_i$ along $\phi$*, i.e.$Y_i=\phi_\ast X_i:=(T\phi)\circ X_i\circ\phi^{-1}$, which equivalently means that $$\phi^\ast(Y_i(f))=X_i(\phi^\ast f),\ \text{for all}\ f\in C^\infty(S).\tag{1}$$ The latter immediately implies that $[Y_i,Y_j]$ is the pushforward of $[X_i,X_j]$ along $\phi$, i.e. $$\phi^\ast([Y_i,Y_j](f))=[X_i,X_j](\phi^\ast f)),\ \text{for all}\ f\in C^\infty(S).\tag{2}$$
Hence, using (1) and (2), for any $f\in C^\infty(S)$, one can compute
$$\phi^\ast((\mathrm{d}(\mathrm{d}f))(Y_i,Y_j))=\phi^\ast(Y_1(Y_2(f))-Y_2(Y_1(f))-[Y_1,Y_2](f))=X_i(\phi^\ast(Y_2(f)))-X_2(\phi^\ast(Y_1(f)))-[X_1,X_2](\phi^\ast f)=X_i(X_2(\phi^\ast f))-X_2(X_1(\phi^\ast f))-[X_1,X_2](\phi^\ast f)$$

In addition the author chooses $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ to be the coordinate frame on $U$, i.e. $X_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$. Hence $[X_i,X_j]=[\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}]=0$, and the latter becomes $$\phi^\ast([Y_i,Y_j](f))=X_i(X_2(\phi^\ast f))-X_2(X_1(\phi^\ast f))=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(\phi^\ast f)-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}(\phi^\ast f)$$ which vanishes identically on $U$ because of the Schwarz's theorem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. This is taken from page no. 183 of the [book](https://dokumen.tips/documents/differential-geometry-thorpe-pdf.html?page=195) in the proof of $(i)$. I was wondering if the following works: $\nabla_{E_j\circ \phi^{-1}}f(x)= df_x(E_j\circ \phi^{-1}(x))=df_{f\circ \phi(y)}(E_j\circ \phi^{-1} \circ \phi(y))=df_{f\circ \phi(y)}(E_j(y))=\nabla_{E_j}(f\circ \phi) $, where $\phi(y)=x$.

Comment: But I know this doesn't make sense as the expressions on LHS and RHS don't have the same domain.

Comment: Dear @Koro thanks for having given more context. In the proof of (i) at page of 183, one reads that (my rephrasing): $E_i(q)=v_i$, where $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is a basis of $T_pS$ (the author denotes it as $S_p$), and further he sets "$V_i=E_i\circ\phi^{-1}$. From the latter (up to some misleading notation) I understand that $E_i$ is a vector field on the manifold $S$ and $V_i$ is a vector field on $R^{n+1}$, so that the relation he writes "$V_i=E_i\circ\phi^{-1}$" should mean that $V_i$ is the image of $E_i$ via $\phi^{-1}$, or equivalently $E_i=\phi_\ast V_i$.

Comment: If one understands the expression $E_i\circ\phi^{-1}$ used by the author as $(\phi^{-1})_* E_i$, then the obvious relation I wrote at the end of my answer implies that $\nabla_{(\phi^{-1})_\ast E_i}(f\circ\phi)=(\nabla_{E_i}f)\circ\phi$

Comment: I think that to make to the domains of LHS and RHS same, $\nabla_{Ej\circ \phi^{-1}}f$ was meant to be defined on $U$ and to do that we can write it as $\nabla_{E_j\circ \phi^{-1}}f\circ \phi$ as $\phi(q)=p$, where p is in S, q is in U.
with this correction, we do get $\nabla_{Ej\circ \phi^{-1}}f\circ \phi= \nabla_{E_j} f\circ \phi$

Comment: Perhaps, in your comment you meant $\phi$ inside i.e., $\nabla_{E_i} (f\circ \phi)$ rather than $(\nabla_{E_i}f)\circ \phi$?

Comment: I am sorry @Koro, I find the notation used in that book a bit confusing, I will try to edit my previous question